# SQLite: Reading a blob from a table that has no rowid

Tags: c++, c, database, sqlite

I'm using the C SQLite library.

I need to obtain the value of a blob from a row. The row is in a table that does not have any row id.

This causes sqlite3_blob_open to return an error - that rowid is not present in the table.

Software like DB Browser for SQLite is able to query the value of these blobs, so there must be a way to do it.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How is my question unclear?

Comment: The documentation says that you can't use this function: [https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_open.html](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_open.html) I use sqlite for over a decade but I don't use blobs and I use it in Qt using the Qt classes so I don't deal directly with the sqlite api.

Comment: From SQLite 3.8.2, it is indeed possible to create a table `WITHOUT ROWID` https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html But this is only allowed if some column is declared as `PRIMARY KEY`, typically a TEXT column. So use that primary key to access your BLOB. But **not** with `sqlite_blob_open`, but with `sqlite3_value_blob`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that a primary key must be used for a WITHOUT ROWID table, but the blob_open function specifically requires an integer rowid. Do you have any information for how to query a blob by text key?

Comment: With my SQLite C++ wrapper, that would be as easy as: `BaseBuffer* blob; db->executeQuery("SELECT data FROM mytable WHERE key=?", "theKey", &blob);`. Of course, using the raw C interface, that would need more code...

Comment: Okay, I'm going to look into https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp and see if it's supported. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use sqlite3_step() in conjunction with sqlite3_column_blob()